# Maui Blazor cannot run on Android but on Windows it works fine

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I wanted to ask for help with compilation a Maui Blazor application.
The application works perfectly if I run it on Windows (no warning, no error), but if I change the target from Windows to Android when I build, I get 2 errors:

> (APT200 expected reference but got (raw string) #0000
> (APT2062 Failed Linking Reference)

I searched on the internet but seems like I'm the only one who gets these errors :(

Both errors lead me to this

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs Condition=" $(AndroidResgenExtraArgs.Contains('--no-version-vectors')) And !($(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs.Contains('--no-version-vectors'))) ">--no-version -vectors $(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs) </AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Aapt2Link
       Condition=" '$(_AndroidResourceDesignerFile)' != '' Or '$(AndroidUseDesignerAssembly)' == 'True' "
       ContinueOnError="$(DesignTimeBuild)"
       DaemonMaxInstanceCount="$(Aapt2DaemonMaxInstanceCount)"
       DaemonKeepInDomain="$(_Aapt2DaemonKeepInDomain)"
       AssemblyIdentityMapFile="$(_AndroidLibrayProjectAssemblyMapFile)"
       ImportsDirectory="$(_LibraryProjectImportsDirectoryName)"
       OutputImportDirectory="$(_AndroidLibrayProjectIntermediatePath)"
       OutputFile="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\resources.apk"
       PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
       JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
       JavaDesignerOutputDirectory="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)"
       CompiledResourceFlatFiles="@(_CompiledFlatFiles)"
       ManifestFiles="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\AndroidManifest.xml"
       AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths="@(_LibraryResourceDirectories)"
       YieldDuringToolExecution="$(YieldDuringToolExecution)"
       ResourceSymbolsTextFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)R.txt"
       ResourceDirectories="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"
       ExtraArgs="$(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs)"
       ToolPath="$(Aapt2ToolPath)"
       ToolExe="$(Aapt2ToolExe)"
       UncompressedFileExtensions="$(AndroidStoreUncompressedFileExtensions)"
   />
   <ItemGroup>
     <FileWrites Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)R.txt" Condition=" Exists ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)R.txt') " />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I tried to remove all dependency thinking that this could be dependency error but nothing was wrong, I got the same errors.

I tried to change .NET from 8 to 7 and 6 but nothing.

But I noticed that it asks my Android version 24 as a minimum android version if I change it to 25 or higher, I get another error like this:

> Error XA1036  AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:minSdkVersion '29' does not match the $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value '24.0' in the project file (if there is no $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value in the project file, then a default value has been assumed).
>
> Either change the value in the AndroidManifest.xml to match the $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value, or remove the value in the AndroidManifest.xml (and add a $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value to the project file if it doesn't already exist).  mauiSpill   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets

But if I set it to 24 or leave it empty, everything starts from the beginning.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022.

Does anyone have any idea about this error?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you are a compatible runtime version installed on Android : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0

Comment: yes it is correct i tried to download it agan but nothing was changed.  And all dependencies are ok there is no warning

Comment: Did you do a clean build after upgrading libraries?  You may have intermediate obj files that need to be recompiled.  I would try use Net 7.0.  I seen number of issues with Net 8.0 preview libraries not working.

Comment: I just tried everithing but it still not working i decided to use Net 7.0 but , some dependencies is not compatible with this version, Anyway thank you,   PS i will never use Net 8.0 :(

Comment: Microsoft often release new version that have lots of bugs.  Eventually the bugs get fixed.